# Find value of constant factor in asymptotic notation

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I have to find the value of constant factor $c_1$ and $c_2$ and $n_0$ in equation for which this equation satisfy:

$$c_1\leq \frac12 - \frac3n \leq c_2$$

Here $n\geq n_0$.

So for what value of $c_1, c_2 $ and $n_0$, this equation will hold,
  Please help me out here.
This is question of chapter name Asymptotic notation, In korman book it's answer is $c_1 = 1/14$, $c_2=1/2$ and $n_0 =7$ , But I am not able to figure out here how he found that value of $c_1, c_2$ and $n_0$.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean $n \ge n_0$, not $n \le n_0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I believe the original post has $n\geq n_0$ but Benjamin Lim made a typo in his edit. I have re-edited appropriately.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Yaa Robert Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That $c_2=\frac{1}{2}$ is common sense.

You understand that the LHS i.e.$(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{3}{n}) \le \frac{1}{2}$, so take the limit

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{3}{n})=\frac{1}{2}$.

Now, once we fix $c_2$, $c_1$ will depend upon $n_0$. As Robert pointed out,$(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{3}{n})\le 0$ till $n_0\le 6$.Hence we have $n_0=7$ and accordingly $c_1=\frac{1}{14}$.

Comment: How did u get c1=1/14 can you plese elaborate it

Comment: Assumption: both $c_1$ & $c_2$ are $\ge 0$. The function $(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{3}{n})$ is increasing wrt $n$. If

$(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{3}{n}) \ge 0$, it implies $n \ge 2 \times 3$ and the least value of $n \ge 6$ is 6, but the value in bracket is $0$ for $n=6$. So, put $n=7$ in the expression and you have the value $\frac{1}{14}$. As the function is increasing wrt n, its value for all $n \ge 7$ will be $\ge \frac{1}{14}$. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: 1) What happens as $n \to \infty$?

2) Note that $\frac{1}{2} - \frac{3}{n}$ is increasing for $n > 0$.

3) There isn't a unique answer, but I think $7$ was chosen because it's the least $n_0$ for which you can take $c_1 > 0$.

Comment: here is there way of finding value og n_0, because we can't guess and check for each possible value of n_0 for c_1 > 0 so plese suggest me some way of finding n_0 value

Comment: Can you solve $\frac{1}{2} - \frac{3}{n} = 0$?